# What's a good way to have a BLE slave notify a Master when something happens?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, notify

I'm setting up the configuration for a BLE Slave/peripheral which has two control variables each of which must be readable/writable from the Master but each can also be modified by buttons on the Slave.  I want to include a mechanism for the Slave to let the Master know if the control variables are changed locally on the Slave via the buttons.  It's expected that the Slave will be out of range of the Master fairly often so there's really two related requirements.  One is that the Slave notify the Master when a control variable is changed locally and the other is the Master needs to learn what the current state of the control variables is whenever a the connection is re-established automatically.  I don't want the Master to be required to poll the Slave when there is a connection because I'm trying to minimize the power consumption at the Slave and such changes will normally be very infrequent. Should I set the "Notify" option in the Characteristic for the Custom Profile containing the two variables or set up a separate Service (or something else) that accomplishes the notification.  It's OK if the Master has to read the Profile/Characteristic when it is notified that a change has occurred.  I think there also needs to be some way that the Slave can tell that the Master has received the notification so it can retry it at the next opportunity.  I'm just learning about BLE and there seems to be many ways to do things and I haven't found any good references that explain the various options and their pros/cons.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the notification property on the characteristic. When there is a new value available, send a notification that contains the new value.

To "sync" the value upon reconnection, just let the master read the characteristic. You could also just send a notification.

If you want to save power on the peripheral I can recommend "slave latency" if you still want low delay.